# Speeding up summation with indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, sum

So lets say **x** is an array of shape (20, 10), and **y** is an array of length 100 containing our desired summation. The array **idx** has the same shape as **x** (20, 10), and it contains indices ranging from 0 to 99.

My goal is to calculate **y**, where **idx** specifies which elements in **x** to sum along **y**. The code bellow does exactly what I want.

```
# Initiate arrays
np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.random((20, 10))
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(100), (20, 10))

# Perform calculation
y = np.zeros(100)
for i, rbf in enumerate(x):
    y[idx[i]] += rbf

print(y)
```

For larger arrays, the above code runs a bit slow because of the *for* loop. Are there any ways to speed up the above code without also using too much memory? Perhaps using *np.einsum()* or lambdas?

Comment: you could make it a function and JIT it with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org)

Comment: `np.add.at(y, idx, x)`, the included implementation is incorrect for `idx[15]` `array([61, 23,  1, 28, 58, 10, 11,  1, 82, 34])` because of the duplicate 1, only the last one is considered in the summation. How do you expect `np.einsum` or *lambda* (?)  to accelerate this task?

Comment: Cheers! That does indeed do the job! Luckily I won't have any duplicated indices in any rows of idx, so that won't be a problem!

Comment: Please clarify the question. The computed result  (*The code bellow does exactly what I want*) doesn't match the explanation and desired result.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I can't find the documentation for `np.add.at`, do you know where it is located ?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I'll try, only problem is I struggle to find the words for describing the problem clearly.

Comment: [np.ufunc.at](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at)

Comment: Consider migrating to codereview.stackexchange.com